# Match and pick date from a String?

Tags: javascript, regex

String:

```
Michael Jordan <br> 1963-02-17 Brooklyn, New York
```

How I can only get `1963-02-17` with regex and JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match this date format specifically (ie YYYY-MM-DD):

```
var str = 'Michael Jordan <br> 1963-02-17 Brooklyn, New York';
var date = str.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)[0]; //"1963-02-17"
```

If it won't always have the date in the string, you will want to check for a valid match first:

```
var str = 'Michael Jordan <br> 19632-17 Brooklyn, New York';
var date = str.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/);
if(date && date[0])
{
    date = date[0];
}
//date is "1963-02-17" or NULL
```

The first example will throw an error if the date is not matched, whereas the second will silently fail and leave `date` equal to `NULL`

Comment: Why do so many people insist on using `[0-9]` when `\d` is shorter, let alone `[0-9]{2}` when `\d\d` is available. Updated to `/\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d/`.

Comment: @Nate legibility for people new to regex, simple as that. I use \d and \w etc myself, but for others that need to better understand what's going on, I always use the more explicit version